# Key command for move cursor to next different value in column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Some Excel jockey told me how to do this once, but I've forgotten.

Basically I have a huge list sorted by a STATUS column.  I'd like to press the down key and go to the next changed value in the column, so I can easily navigate all statuses.  I know there's a certain key command do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the rows weren't _grouped_

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  I distinctly remember this person sorting by a certain column, and then hitting a hotkey + down arrow to skip to the row where the value changed.

Comment: Hold `ctrl` + `shift` while you press two keys in sequence: `↓` once to select the rest of the column, then `|` (vertical bar, backslash key) once to select column changes and jump to the next one (from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/873242/is-there-a-way-to-skip-down-to-the-next-change-in-value-in-excel)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to skip down to the next change in value in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/873242/is-there-a-way-to-skip-down-to-the-next-change-in-value-in-excel)

Comment: From the duplicate question: Highlight the column, press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`\\`